# 0 base scale stock tickers?

Tags: stock-markets

Are there any stock tickers that offer graphs with $0 at the bottom?  IMHO, the variable scale makes it difficult to tell how a stock is doing, and I would like for the x-axis to always be at $ == 0.  Are there any tickers that are like this or that have an option for this?

Comment: I agree... but I haven't seen any yet

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to compare stocks you are better off comparing returns rather than prices directly. This is because a change of $1 on a stock priced at $5 will be much more pronounced than the same absolute change on $550. Since professional investors (as opposed to traders, key difference here) tend to work in either percentage returns or log returns these charts are commonly available from investment management platforms. Since the mean return for most equities is just above 0 and most stocks have periods of negative returns - even if it is just one hour - returns charts will almost always include 0.

A key here is to realise that in comparing stocks you are more interested in the percentage that the change in the stock price would have on the amount you invest than you are in the actual price of the stock. In fact the only difference is the number of whole units you can buy which will affect your P&L less than the absolute price of the stock.

Comment: This "percent return" talk is precisely my point.  If I know my purchase price, then the percent return is *easily* visible on a price chart that has a 0$ baseline.  It's just the fraction of the curve that is above your purchase price.  OTOH the variable scale chart is useless in this regard.

Comment: If that's precisely your point why not use one of the return graphs?

Comment: $0-based graphs (the kind the OP wants) show percentages accurately, and non-$0-based graphs don't.